# Supremum - why this holds?

Tags: real-analysis

Could you please explain to me why this holds?
$$\sup_{x \in (0,5)}\left|\frac{x}{n}\cdot \ln \frac{x}{n}  \right| \neq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{}R^+}\left|\frac{x}{n}\cdot \ln \frac{x}{n}  \right|  $$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I think that both sup values are $\infty$ but it is incorrect.

Comment: What is $n$? A fixed natural number?

Comment: Its a natural number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ is a fixed natural number, your bet is wrong: they are indeed different.

First hint: what is $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}x\ln x$?

Second hint: define $f(t)=t\ln t$ for $t>0$ and $f(0)=0$; then $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, and
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,5)}\left|\frac{x}{n}\ln\frac{x}{n}\right|\le
\sup_{x\in[0,5]}\left|\,f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right|
$$
What can you say about the number on the right?

---

(Added after accept)

Since the function $f$ is continuous on $[0,5]$ it has a maximum and a minimum in that interval (which depends on $n$), so
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,5)}\left|\frac{x}{n}\ln\frac{x}{n}\right|
$$
is finite. However, since $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$, we have
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\left|\frac{x}{n}\ln\frac{x}{n}\right|=\infty
$$

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \to 0}x\cdot ln (x)=0$?

Comment: @Evil_Genius Yes; what can you say, then?

Comment: @Evil_Genius I added a second hint

Comment: Well ... the 1st value should be $$\sup_{x\in(0,5)}\left|\frac{x}{n}\ln\frac{x}{n}\right| \le \frac{5}{n}ln \frac{5}{n}$$

Comment: @Evil_Genius Not necessarily (and indeed false in general); but can that supremum be $\infty$?

Comment: It can not, I calculated the limit of $\left|\frac{x}{n}\cdot \ln \frac{x}{n}  \right|$ as n to infinity it should be zero

Comment: @Evil_Genius You have to keep $n$ fixed; computing the limit with respect to $n$ is meaningless, here.